# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple'

Tags: python, flask, testing

While I am testing my API I recently started to get the error below.

```
        if request is None:
>           builder = EnvironBuilder(*args, **kwargs)
E           TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple'

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py:1081: TypeError
```

As I read from the documentation in the newer version of `Werkzeug` the `as_tuple` parameter is removed.

Part of my test code is

```py
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

@pytest.fixture(name='test_client')
def _test_client() -> FlaskClient:
    app = create_app()
    return app.test_client()


class TestPeerscoutAPI:
    def test_should_have_access_for_status_page(self, test_client: FlaskClient):
        response = test_client.get('/api/status')
        assert _get_ok_json(response) == {"status": "OK"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As of version 2.1.0, `werkzeug` has removed the `as_tuple` argument to `Client`. Since Flask wraps werkzeug and you're using a version that still passes this argument, it will fail. See [the exact change on the GitHub PR here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/2276/files#diff-e00d1f616a746837a6f12a882341f83276f8b0b2781800695c65c5b7ed041db3R1038-R1120).

You can take one of two paths to solve this:

1. Upgrade flask
2. Pin your werkzeug version

```
# in requirements.txt
werkzeug==2.0.3
```

Answer (score 16):

Adding to Christian Di Lorenzo's answer

1. Upgrade flask

```
# in requirements.txt
Flask==2.1.1
```

2. Pin your werkzeug version

```
# in requirements.txt
werkzeug==2.0.3
```