# Unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple' error in Flask even after upgrading werkzeug version to 2.0.3

Tags: python, flask

While I am testing my API I recently started to get the error below.

```
        if request is None:
>           builder = EnvironBuilder(*args, **kwargs)
E           TypeError: EnvironBuilder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple'
```

Code:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def client():
    app = my_app()
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_new_func(client, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(UnitPricing, 'find_unit_price', find_unit_pricing)
    monkeypatch.setattr(FullPricing, 'find_full_price', find_full_pricing)

    response = client.post("/price/calc", json=input_payload)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert json.loads(response.data) == output_data
```

In one of the solutions, it was suggested to pin `werkzeug` version to `2.0.3` and my requirement.txt file is meeting this condition but I'm still getting the error.

[TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_tuple'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661851/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-as-tuple)

```
> pip show Flask werkzeug
Name: Flask
Version: 2.0.2
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\xyz\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires: click, itsdangerous, Jinja2, Werkzeug
Required-by: Flask-Session, Flask-SQLAlchemy
---
Name: Werkzeug
Version: 2.0.3
Summary: The comprehensive WSGI web application library.
Home-page: https://palletsprojects.com/p/werkzeug/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\xyz\venv\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: Flask
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "_my requirement.txt file is meeting this condition_" you actually have to make sure you install that version of the package as well. `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Obviously Abdul, it's been taken care of.

Comment: Please [edit] and show us the output of `python -m pip show Flask werkzeug`

Comment: added the output

Comment: This output is for the same python interpreter you're using to run your tests? Is it possible you forgot to activate a virtual environment?

Comment: yes, This is for the same python interpreter I'm using to run my tests. Also, I'm running this in a virtual environment.